# Would it be wrong to save the permalinks as a postmeta and regenerate it on save post?

Tags: permalinks

I was wondering about the permalinks. They are built on the fly but they are pretty much always the same. It seems like a waste of processing time and databse queries on every request.

Why not store them into the database and regenerate it when needed ?

What's wrong with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why waste storing (potentially) huge amounts of redundant, duplicate data, when you can store 1 pattern and only the unique "slug" for each post?

The processing power involved in generating permalinks "on the fly" is **so** insignificant in comparison to merely loading WordPress, it'd be like trying to make your car go faster by driving naked to save weight...

Comment: Cool comparison Hahaha

Comment: It depends on the pattern. Mine involves having the category id/slug into the permalink. Problem is not for 1 permalink. On that we agree. It is when you havel dozens of posts (like a search engine page results or category archive) and every single time you redo the same process, involving a database request just to grab the same link over and over again.

But you're right it probably is insignificant regarding Wordpress and plugins and theme loading even with a custom permalink pattern as I have.

Comment: There shouldn't be too many db requests - WordPress has an internal cache system (in memory by default), so even in a loop, once that object (be it a category, post, whatever) is in the cache, that's it.